# How to break apart a List of nested Expressions into Lists of single-level Expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda

Say I have a `List<Expression<Func<SomeModel, object>>>` that looks like this:

```
x => x.Property1,
x => x.Property1.P1ChildProperty1,
x => x.Property1.P1ChildProperty2,
x => x.Property2,
x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty1,
x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty2,
x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty3
```

Is there some way I can iterate over that list, and produce a new set of lists that only go one-level deep, like this:

List 1:

```
x => x.Property1,
x => x.Property2
```

List 2:

```
y => y.P1ChildProperty1,
y => y.P1ChildProperty2
```

List 3:

```
z => z.P2ChildProperty1,
z => z.P2ChildProperty2,
z => z.P2ChildProperty3
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I've tried a number of things, but none came close to what I need to do, which is why I'm asking here.  I think the actual question/concept is clear enough for people to understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that. But it depends on your class structure.

```
var items = new List<Expression<Func<SomeModel, object>>>
            {
                x => x.Property1,
                x => x.Property1.P1ChildProperty1,
                x => x.Property1.P1ChildProperty2,
                x => x.Property2,
                x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty1,
                x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty2,
                x => x.Property2.P2ChildProperty3
            };
Func<LambdaExpression, Expression<Func<object, object>>> reBase = 
            x =>
            {
                var memExpr = (MemberExpression)x.Body;
                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "x");
                var typedParam = Expression.Convert(param, memExpr.Member.DeclaringType);
                var property = Expression.Property(typedParam, memExpr.Member.Name);
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(property, param);
            };

var groupedItems = (from item in items
                    group item by ((MemberExpression)item.Body).Member.DeclaringType into g
                    select g.Select(x => reBase(x)).ToList()).ToList();
```

After that `groupedItems` contains the splitted re-based list as you want.

The problem is that it asks for the declaring type. This will only work if you declare the types having this properties:

- `SomeModel`: `Property1` of type `Child1`, `Property2` of type `Child2`
- `<Child1>`: `P1ChildProperty1`, `P1ChildProperty2`
- `<Child2>`: `P1ChildProperty1`, `P1ChildProperty2`, `P1ChildProperty3`

I'm not sure that this will help you in general. Maybe you should have a deeper look into expression trees to find a bettet way to split your list.

Keep in mind that this changes the lambda signature from `Func<SomeModel, object>` to `Func<object, object>`.

Comment: This is very close, but doesn't quite create the lists I'm after.  It does group them, but it doesn't "re-base" them to be one level deep.

Comment: Ups - now I understand your requests. Sorry. But it's still possible. You've to create new expressions dynamically and recursive by parsing through the property path. I've to think about it.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you couldn't use `Func<SomeModel, object>` because the return type of `Property1` meight not be of type `SomeModel`. Maybe you've to change to `Func<object, object>` and you've to cast in every lambda but in that case all lambdas have the same signature. (Maybe dynamic will work but I'm not sure if it's usable in expression trees.)

Comment: @gnack I changed the code so that it re-bases the lambdas. Sorry that I misread the question for the first time.